# Overflow Hidden Not working correctly with radius border

Tags: css, hover, overflow

I am trying to create a nice hover effect for a my project i am working on and the overflow hidden doesn't seem to be working in safari Take a look. [learn.michaelscimeca.com](http://learn.michaelscimeca.com)

HTML:

```
<div class="thumnnail">
  <img class="mainbg" src="img/shoppee.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="textbox">
    <img src="/img/eye.png" alt="">
    <span class="launch"><a href="http://www.shoppedelee.com">View Project</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumnnail .textbox .launch a {
  margin-left: -78px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #1c51c8;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  /* this is for the animation effect to bring the textbox down to up and up to down */

  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.thumnnail .textbox .launch a:hover {
  background-color: #093db4;
}
.thumnnail:hover {
  border: 10px solid #0d46c8;
  /* this is to alter the border on rollover */

  border-radius: 100%;
  /* this is to round out the div tag */

  /* to get rid of the greyscale on rollover */

  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
  overflow: hidden! important;
}
.thumnnail:hover img {
  /* width:120%;
    height:120%;*/

}
.thumnnail:hover .textbox {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's good practice to provide sample markup and code here, and only reference your site to illustrate the issue as a whole. Otherwise, you're asking others to do a lot of hunting around for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your transition from:

```
transition: all .5s ease;
```

to:

```
transition: border .5s ease;
```

And then post your CSS and HTML so that other people can see what the problem was.

Comment: Don't know. I'm still seeing an issue in Safari, even after changing the transition to only affect the border. I agree, however... the OP needs to post code.

Comment: argh yeah I guess I don't really have access to Safari right now - should have paid more attention there.

Comment: `.thumbnail` should transition `border-color` only, not `border-width`.  It should also transition `filter`.  `.textbox` should transition `height`.  So: `.thumbnail { transition: border-color .5s ease, filter .5s ease; } .textbox { transition: height .5s ease; }`

Comment: Do you want to repost that as your own answer or should I add it to mine?

Comment: yea I tired all suggestions. Still no luck :(